# SQL - Select statement using LastIndex

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, user-defined-functions

I have a resultset which has **ProductURL** stored :

```
accessoires/abc/285/P187654
accessoires/abc/285/D18765432
accessoires/abc/285/A1876543
```

I need to get the final part of the URL i.e. anything that is after the final **'/'** that appears in the URL.

I have a function which gives me the LASTINDEX :

```
SELECT [LAST_INDEX] (ProductURL,'/')
```

But how do I run a Select statement with this function inside a substring:

```
SELECT Substring(ProductURL,SELECT [LAST_INDEX] (ProductURL,'/'),len(ProductURL))
from data
```

This does not seem to work? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT  Substring(ProductURL, [LAST_INDEX] (ProductURL, '/'), len(ProductURL))
FROM    data
```